# Open browser window using javascript then detect when closed

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of trouble getting something to work that I thought would be quite straightforward.

I want to be able to open a new browser window/tab, then detect when it is closed so I can refresh elements on the screen that opened the window/tab.

So to open:

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=500,height=400');
```

To detect closing:

```
win.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
     console.log('closed');
     // code...
});
```

I have tried both `beforeunload` and `onbeforeunload` but neither trigger the event and log to the console. Using 'unload' works but fires twice, both when the window opens and when it closes.

The only thing I've been able to get working is this, but I'm not super keen on using timers to track the status of opened windows.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
    if(win.closed) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log('closed');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Edit: Ok I think I've found the problem, the `onbeforeunload` event has to be attached AFTER the window has loaded, when I did this inside the onload event it worked, and then tried with a timer to wait for the page to load and it worked. So basically the event listener was executing too quickly.

Comment: socket.io comes to mind: notify the server when the window is closed, then send a message to the 1st window

Comment: What advantage would `socket.io` give over `setInterval`? @David if you found the solution you may post it as answer. Answering own question is good with SO.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've found the problem, the onbeforeunload event has to be attached AFTER the window has loaded, when I did this inside the onload event it worked, and then tried with a timer to wait for the page to load and it worked. So basically the event listener was executing too quickly.